# How can I add Hour and minute in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I add hours and minutes in a single query?

I tried this

```
Select DATEADD(hh,23.59,CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME))
```

I need to ad 23 hours and 59 minutes, but my code only adds the hours.  Why?

Comment: DATEADD with Minute and 23.59*60?  Or two calls on DATEADD? (one for hours, one for minutes)

Comment: If this is for defining the end point of some period, you should be aware that it's usually much *easier* to compute an exclusive endpoint (and use `<` rather than `<=`) than to compute the inclusive endpoint. E.g. is it currently your intention to exclude anything that happens *during* the final minute of that day?

Comment: @MatBailie 23.59 will not work since you need 59 minutes as a percentage of 23 hour units. For your calculation to work you would need 23.983333333*60. I would suggest using for ultimate accuracy (23*60)+59 = 1439. Making the final query "SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1439, CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME))". I just noticed this is in the answer below...

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
Select DATEADD(minute, 23*60 + 59, CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME))
```

EDIT:

If you are getting a float/decimal value such as 23.59, then you can do:

```
Select DATEADD(minute, FLOOR(@hhmm) * 60 + (@hhmm - FLOOR(@hhmm)) * 100, CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME))
```

Note:  You can also use:

```
Select DATEADD(minute, FLOOR(@hhmm) * 60 + (@hhmm % 1) * 100, CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME))
```

But I find this usage of the modulo operator slightly off-kilter.

Comment: Math(s) to the rescue!

Comment: Thanks I tried this how do I split the float value that comes from db 23.59 it would verify it can have any value like 20 , 18.30 15.22 how do I multiply with hour part like 23*60 and add the minute part 59

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `DATEADD()` twice:

```
 Select DATEADD(minute,59,DATEADD(hh,23,CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below code for adding time part to a date.

```
SELECT DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME)), '23:59:00.000')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `datepart` argument, in your case `hh`, is part of date to which an **integer number** is added. So the `DATEADD` function just ignores any fractional part of your input.

To get result you want, you need to either use `DATEADD` twice, adding 23 hours and then 59 minutes, or add one day to your date and subtract 1 minute, like this:

```
Select DATEADD(MI, -1, CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME) + 1)
```

---

See also [Microsoft's documentation on `DATEADD`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Toby, I edited my answer, hope it answer his question.

Answer (score 0):

another method : you can do by adding one day and then substract minute

**Output is same**

```
  select DATEADD(minute, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1,CAST('2016-07-08' AS DATETIME)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL I do it like this and it work fine to me

```
 SELECT (NVL(TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (TIME_1, 'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI')
            - TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (TIME_2, 'HH24:MI'), 'HH24:MI'),
            0) * 24) * 60 in_min 
 FROM dual
```